# Timer not stopping

Tags: android, time, countdown

**Ok ths is becomming annoying!
I can't really stop the timer,only pause it...
I have a function that makes x be a new timer everytime the function is called.What I need,is to sometimes stop the timer and start allover again.The problem is that if I use cancel,it pauses it and when I call the function to make a new one,it actually continues the one that wa s paused! Please help me so I can sleep...**

```
public void countdown(){


        final TextView textic = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);

        x = new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            textic.setText("Seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);

        }

        public void onFinish() {
            textic.setText("Time expired");
            idiot();
            getfirstquestion();

        }
        };

        x.start();
    }
```

**That's the function,and the x is decleared as a global variable at the beginning.What is need is: when I press a button(even 100 times) make the current timer stop,and start a really new one(like in that function).**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just cancel the old one before you create the new one.

```
public void countdown(){
    final TextView textic = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);

    if (x != null) {
        x.cancel();
    }

    x = new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        textic.setText("Seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);

    }

    public void onFinish() {
        textic.setText("Time expired");
        idiot();
        getfirstquestion();

    }
    };

    x.start();
}
```